# jQuery .get() DOM weirdness

Tags: jquery, dom

Quick rundown - I'm adding a class of 'checked' to image elements when a user clicks on them.
Clicking my 'Next' button hides the 'choose-photos' div and shows the confirm div, injecting in the selected photos, like so:

```
$('.next').click(function () {
  $('.user-photos').attr('id', 'step-two');
  $('.choose-photos').hide();
  var selected = $('.checked').get();
  $('.confirm-batch').show().html(selected);
}
});
```

The .get() method is working quite well; however, if you click to back to step 1 and choose new photos, whichever photos you've selected are gone from the DOM.

```
$('.choose').click(function (){
 $('.user-photos').attr('id', 'step-one');
 $('.confirm-batch').hide().html('');
 $('.choose-photos').show();
}
```

});

Is there a way to get those 'checked' items back in the 'choose' div without reloading the page? Basically just resetting the process.

Comment: Maybe you want to clone the elements first: `$('.checked').clone().get()`.

Comment: `get()` returns an array of elements, wouldn't you have to loop over them?

Comment: Cloning the elements would work. Alternatively, if you don't care about the order of the elements, you could shift them back from `.confirm-batch` to `.choose-photos` in much the same manner as before.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised that calling `.html()` with an array of elements even works. The jQuery API seems to indicate that it wouldn't.

Comment: I was also very surprised it worked...I was leery but chalked it up to good fortune and moved on. I was positive I'd have to send them to an array and return the values, etc and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery overloads some of its methods with stupid behavior.

One example is that it allows this...

```
var selected = $('.checked').get();
$('.confirm-batch').show().html(selected);
```

It looks like you're inserting an HTML string rendered from the `selected` elements, but you're not, it's *reloacting* them, as you normally would with DOM nodes.

As a solution, you could either clone them, or better, just put them back where you found them instead of destroying them with `.html('')`

Comment: Is this some undocumented usage of `html`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: It appears to be. They would be better off just letting it insert the `.toString()` value of the element *(even though it wouldn't be the content desired)* instead of giving it DOM manipulation capability.

Comment: I'd argue that they would be better off having it do nothing or adding this behaviour to the documentation, rather than continuing to do something (albeit less disruptive) that's still undocumented.

Comment: .clone() does the trick. Got tripped up since my train of thought was definitely what you mentioned it looks like. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I agree, though I'd rather see it add a string like `"[object HTMLImageElement"]` than to have it added to the documentation.